# f2=sys.argv[1] IndexError: list index out of range while trying to get argument from bash file

Tags: python, bash

I am trying a small project to read the the simple csv file by using bash file and python unforunately its shows

> list index out of range error for argv[1]

**main.py**

```
import sys
import csv
def main(file_name):

    fp = open(file_name)
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    points = []
    for row in reader:
        x = row[0]        
        y = row[1]
        print(y)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   if len(sys.argv) > 0:
       file_name = sys.argv[1]
       main(file_name)
   else:
       print "<filename> must be the first argument"
```

#BAsh file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
chmod +x ./main.py
for f in ./sample_data/*.csv  

do
printf "%-28s" $f
./main.py $f
done
```

Comment: how you run the above file?

Comment: yes iran the above code in pyton3.4.2

Comment: Of course, you could opt to loop through your input files in Python.

Comment: @rbp i checked and i realised its not passing argument i dont know why it is not passing

Comment: @rbp  i got your point and checked in the code for array length i can get argv[0] but argv[1] something wrong with passing arguments . iam running on windows with python 3.4 i so bash file is same for windows and linux?

Comment: @rbp can you command the code here if you dont mind

Comment: @rbp thanks for that  i did the same checking my question is how can i get arguments .? is .sh files work on windows?

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if `$f` contains "extra" characters that can be somehow interpreted by BASH, such as `&` and `||`. Anyway, it's better to use `./main.py "$f"` so `$f` was interpreted as a single argument.

Consider this example

```
f="echo hello"
echo $f
```

This produces: `echo hello` but not `hello` as `$f` is interpreted as an argument.

Comment: I  tried this one even #!/usr/bin/env bash
chmod +x ./main.py
for f="hello" 
printf "%-28s" $f
./main.py $f
 does not work

Comment: @user3600866, run `./main.py "$f"`

Comment: nope its not working stil shows same error is that working in your machine

Comment: @user3600866, what's your file name?

Comment: @user3600866, I'm sorry, I meant, what's your csv file's name? Does it contain any "unusual" characters mentioned in my answer?

Comment: data.csv  its works without bash file but i need to use  bash script

Comment: @user3600866, try `python yourscript.py "$f"` then. (Without a `./`)

Comment: no way same error is that problem with my python version

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your python file must start with `#!/usr/bin/python`
Also it throws error `NameError: name 'reader' is not defined` because your for loop is not inside main function.
After moving that for inside main function your code works.

Comment: Everything's OK with the code as it gets interpreted by Python.